# AWS Cognito - Trigger reset password email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I need to trigger a password reset email from inside a lambda function on aws.

I tried the CognitoIdentityServiceProvider > adminResetUserPassword, but this appears to only set the account as requiring a reset and asks the user the next time they log in, without actually sending an email.

Is there a way to force send the email / trigger the event programmatically?

Comment: It seems like your question is simply asking what AWS Cognito API to call to send a reset email password. The fact you are writing the code in Node, and running the code on Lambda, would be entirely irrelevant, and yet those are the things you focus on in your question.

Comment: it depends, the node sdk (eg. CognitoIdentityServiceProvider) may already have this functionality somewhere and I don't know about it, if it does I would use that otherwise it would be the api.

Comment: All the AWS SDKs have the same functionality, they are just calling the AWS API, which is where the actual functionality is.

Comment: What happens if you call the `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider > forgotPassword` method instead?

Comment: it marks the account as 'reset required', but doesn't actually send out an email, it needs to be handled by the front end when the user logs in / asks them to reset password.

Comment: The documentation for the `forgotPassword` method says "Calling this API causes a message to be sent to the end user with a confirmation code that is required to change the user's password."  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#forgotPassword-property

Comment: Note that if an account is already in "password reset" mode, Cognito will not send any password reset emails.

Comment: forgotPassword did it, funny thing is, it still sends the email, which is great. Thanks chum. You should put it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [forgotPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#forgotPassword-property) method says "Calling this API causes a message to be sent to the end user with a confirmation code that is required to change the user's password."